# JavaScript button on click navigate to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, button

I was having some problem with the HTML and JavaScript validation. So basically I got multiple fields and I will perform a validation before moving to another HTML page. Here is the code:

```
<fieldset>
    Name* <input id="name" type="text" name="name"> </input>
    NRIC/Passport No* <input id="nric" type="text" name="nric" > </input>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Pay now!" onclick="validate()"/> 
</fieldset>
```

My Javascript:

```
function validate(){
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var nric = document.getElementById('nric').value;
var submit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit').value;

if(name == null || name == ""){
    alert('Please enter your name. Do not leave it blank before proceed to the next field.');
}
else if(nric == null || nric == ""){
    alert('Please enter your NRIC. Do not leave it blank before proceed to the next field.');
}else{
    window.location.href = '../successful.html';
}
}
```

I tried to perform a validation before moving to successful.html. The validation works, however, when I tried to navigate to another page, it was telling me the web page is not found. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you load the successful.html page manually?  I'm just wondering if the page is in fact not found.

Comment: Try to specify absolute url to this `sucessful.htlm` page

Comment: Your HTML is not correct since you specifyied closure tag for `<input />` element which is an orphan element.

Comment: Yes, I managed to load the successful.html. Absolute? But I thought relative would be better as the files will be keep moving from one computer to another.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = '../successful.html';`

This line above can be traduced like following :

1. I want to navigate to another file `window.location.href`
2. This file is outside my current folder
3. Precisely, one folder backward  `../`
4. The file I want to access is named `successful.html`

Your redirection will suppose you have the following project organization :

```
\...
    \MYPRECEDENTFOLDER
        successful.html
        \MYCURRENTFOLDER
            myCurrentfile.html
```

You have to check where is located successful.html. Another solution is to call for the absolute URL (beware of changes in URL, basically when you go from localhost to another URL).

Comment: the successful.html is in the same folder as my current page.

Comment: So you should remove the double-dot and the slash to precise your file is located in the same folder as your current file like this : `window.location.href = 'successful.html';`